# How to make a style hyperlink-able?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I created custom heading styles and set their outline level appropriately (`Paragraph -> General -> Outline level`). I did it because I need all headings/outlines multilevel-numbered.

But when I try to hyperlink some text to a `Place in This Document`, I don't see the text entries with this style.

How can I make a style hyperlink-able?

Comment: You mean you want the headings reference-able, that it can be referenced by hyperlinks :)

Comment: @Sanny, heading 1 to 3 *are* reference-able, but 4 to 9 aren't. But this is only half the story - I also want the heading to be multilevel-numbered, (1. and then 1.1. and then 1.1.1. and so on...) so I have to create custom headings. I was thinking that making them `Outline level` makes them reference-able, but I was wrong. So the question is how to make custom style reference-able like the default headings.

Comment: I'm not on my PC. However, as far as I know it's better to modify the default headings so you can enjoy their features. You may make your custom styles to have the same features with the default headings, but I'll leave it till I'm sure and check it on a PC.

Comment: I don't get why headings 1-3 can be linked to but 4-9 can't.Or are 4-9 the ones that you created custom styles for? You can associate each level of a multilevel list with a specific style; so the fact that you need numbering doesn't automatically mean you have to create custom styles. Sanny's right, you should modify the default headings instead of creating custom styles. Otherwise, the only way to create hyperlinks to custom styles (even custom styles based on default styles that you _can_ link to) is to add bookmarks. You can create cross-reference links to them though, if they're numbered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having two troubles: 1. You want to refer to a text formatted in a style you created; and 2. You want to use multi-level numbering on Headings styles.

I checked on my PC, Word 2016 on Windows 10, for any solution to make user's styles to get some of the features that Word's default Headings enjoy, specifically referring to them. Unfortunately, you can't; quoting from [this page](http://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/usebuiltinheadingstyles.html)

> If you use custom styles, your only option is to bookmark every
>   heading individually and pray to the God of your choice that you edit
>   your heading text very carefully around the bookmarks.

Based on the information above, you must have used a custom style, and thus the text does not appear in the dialogue box `Insert Hyperlink` > `Place in this document`.

What you want is to use the default Headings styles and modify them to add multi-level numbering. This can be done in different ways, but an easy way is to  use the command `Update Heading X to match selection`, considering that you are going to modify 9 styles:

1. Type 9 paragraphs (write one word and key in `enter`).
2. Reveal the `Styles` panel (for Windows, hit `ALT + CTRL + SHIFT + S`)
3. Apply the style `Heading 1` to the first paragraph by placing the cursor inside it and clicking the `Heading 1` from the Style panel,  `Heading 2` to the second paragraph,  `Heading 3` to the third paragraph, and so forth.
4. Select all of the paragraphs and apply your preferable multi-level list. They will be all in level 1 so;
5. Beginning with the second paragraph, put the cursor at its start (right after the numbering part) and key in `Tab` from your keyboard. Repeat this so every paragraph is in the next level from the previous one.
6. Select the first paragraph, and from the `Style` panel, right-click `Heading 1`, then choose `Update Heading 1 to match selection`. Repeat it with the second paragraph with `Heading 2` and so forth;

Be careful to right-click the corresponding style and not another heading style. Be careful not to left-click the style or you'll apply the old style without the numbering part!

Now you have a set of Heading styles with multi-level list. You can remove the 9 paragraphs you wrote during this course and start using the modified Headings to where they are applicable in your document.